# Cant get observable with embedded setInterval to work in test

Tags: angular, typescript

I've written a little controller class for countdown timer.  Works fine on the web page, but I can't get my unit test to work.  I'm not sure if the problem is the way I'm running my test, or the something in the class itself.

```
Here is the class under test:

import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs'

    export class CountDownTimerController {
         public secondsTimer$ : Observable<any>;
         private counter : number;
         private _counterActive: boolean;
        
         public get counterActive(): boolean {
            return this._counterActive;
        }
         
        constructor() {
            this.counter = -1;
            this._counterActive = false;    
            this.startTicker();
         }
    
         start() {
            this._counterActive = true;
            console.clear();
            console.log(`Started, _counterActive is ${this._counterActive}`)
         }
         pause() {
            this._counterActive = false;
         }
         reset() {
             this.pause()  
             this.counter = 0;
         }
         public get count() : number {
            return this.counter
         }
         private startTicker() { 
             if (this.secondsTimer$) {return}
             let self = this;
   
            this.secondsTimer$ = new Observable(observer => {
                let interval = setInterval(() => {
                    console.log(`Time: ${Date.now()} interval triggered.  counterActive ${self._counterActive} counter: ${self.counter}`)
                    if (self._counterActive) {
                        self.counter = self.counter + 1;
                        observer.next(self.counter)
                    }
                }, 1000);
                return function unsubscribe() {clearInterval(interval);
                }
            })
         }
    }
```

Here is the test I'm running:

```
fit('starts counting seconds when start is called', async ()=>{
        console.log("starrt test")
        let controller = new CountDownTimerController();
        expect(controller.count).toBe(-1,"Should be initialized to -1");
        expect(controller.counterActive).toBeFalse;
        controller.start(); 
        expect(controller.counterActive).toBeTrue
        console.log(`Time: ${Date.now()} controller started`)
        await utils.sleep(2000);  //WAIT FOR TWO TICKS OF SetInterval
        expect(controller.counterActive).toBeTrue();
        console.log(`Time: ${Date.now()} Waited 2 seconds`)
        console.log(`Counter: ${controller.count}`)
 --->   expect(controller.count).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1,`Ticker should be 1 or more at time ${Date.now()}` )
        //FAILS ON THE PRECEDING LINE
       console.log("end test")
    });
```

In case of interest, here is utils.sleep implementation:

```
 export const sleep = (ms: number) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

And here is the console output.

```
Started, _counterActive is true count-down-timer-controller.spec.ts:37 
Time: 1625597279827 controller started count-down-timer-controller.spec.ts:40 
Time: 1625597281829 Waited 2 seconds count-down-timer-controller.spec.ts:41 
Counter: -1 count-down-timer-controller.spec.ts:44 
end test
debug.js:15 FAILED CountDownTimerController starts counting seconds when start is called
debug.js:21 Error: Expected -1 to be greater than or equal 2, 'Ticker should be 1 or more at time 1625597281829'.
    at <Jasmine>
    at count-down-timer-controller.spec.ts:42
    at <Jasmine>
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
debug.js:6 Skipped 27 tests
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never subscribed to the observable (this.secondsTimer$), so the interval is never created/triggered.